# Quicksort skipping one element

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

So today i tried to implement a quicksort. It's almost working but somehow skips one element.

`example : 5 2 8 2 3 4 1 5 7 -5 -1 -9 2 4 5 7 6 1 4`

`output : -5 -1 -9 1 2 2 3 2 1 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 8`

In this case it skips `-9`. Here is code of the function.

```
test = quicksort_asc(0,size,tab,size) // this is function call 

int quicksort_asc(int l, int r, int tab[], int tabSize) //l is first index, r is last index, tabSize is tabsize-1 generally
{
    int i,buffer,lim,pivot,flag=0;
    if(l == r)
        return 0;

    lim = l-1;
    pivot = tab[r-1];
    printf("pivot:%d\n",pivot);
    for (i = l; i <= r-1; ++i)
    {
        if(tab[i] < pivot) {
            lim++;
            buffer = tab[lim];
            tab[lim] = tab[i];
            tab[i] = buffer;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0)
        return 0;
    buffer = tab[lim+1];
    tab[lim+1] = pivot;
    tab[r-1] = buffer;
    quicksort_asc(l,lim+1,tab,lim+1);//left side
    quicksort_asc(lim+1,tabSize,tab,tabSize);//right side

}
```

This is my array length count code. 100 is maximum size, 0 is a stop value.
Count is size.

```
 int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        test = scanf("%d",&vec[i]);
        if(vec[i] == 0) break;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: Provide a working code please so we can actually help.

Comment: You mean that? check edit

Comment: Have you walked through it in a debugger to see if it behaves as expected?

Comment: No tbh, i still don't know how to use debugger

Comment: You've got a spectacular opportunity right here to learn. It takes about 20 minutes to get familiar with the basics and that short amount of time will quickly page huge dividends.

Comment: @Cnewbiec Show how the array is defined and how the function is called.

Comment: Ok, I believe you. I will learn it

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow i edited my post to show what you asked for

Comment: The part `2 3 2 1 4` is not sorted properly either, btw

Comment: If `"l is first index, r is last index"`, then `test = quicksort_asc(0,size,tab,size)` should be `test = quicksort_asc(0,size-1,tab,size)` if `size` is the number of elements.

Comment: @Eraklon How can he provide a working code if his code does not work?:)

Comment: If you're running Linux, I suggest `gdb`. If not, I still suggest `gdb`, but it will be harder to install.

Answer (score 1):

It seems nobody hurries to help you.:)

For starters the last parameter is redundant.

```
int quicksort_asc(int l, int r, int tab[], int tabSize);
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

All you need is the pointer to the first element of the array and starting and ending indices.

Also instead of the type `int` for the indices it is better to use the type `size_t`. However as you are using the expression statement

```
lim = l-1;
```

then o'k let the indices will have the type int though you could use another approach without this expression statement.

So the function should be declared like

```
void quicksort_asc( int tab[], int l, int r );
```

The variable `flag` is redundant. When it is equal to 0 it means that all elements before the pivot value are greater than or equal to it. But nevertheless you have to swap the pivot value with the first element that is greater than or equal to the pivot.

This loop

```
for (i = l; i <= r-1; ++i)
```

has one iteration redundant. It should be set like

```
for (i = l; i < r-1; ++i)
```

This call

```
quicksort_asc(lim+1,tabSize,tab,tabSize);
              ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
```

shall be substituted for this call

```
quicksort_asc( lim + 2, r, tab );
               ^^^^^^^  ^^
```

because the pivot value is not included in this sub-array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quicksort_asc( int tab[], int l, int r )
{
    if ( l + 1 < r )
    {
        int lim = l - 1;

        int pivot = tab[r - 1];

        for ( int i = l; i < r - 1; ++i )
        {
            if ( tab[i] < pivot ) 
            {
                lim++;

                int tmp = tab[lim];
                tab[lim] = tab[i];
                tab[i] = tmp;
            }
        }

        tab[r - 1] = tab[lim + 1];
        tab[lim + 1] = pivot;
        quicksort_asc( tab, l, lim + 1 );
        quicksort_asc( tab, lim + 2, r );
    }       
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = { 5, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7, -5, -1, -9, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4 };
    const int N = ( int )( sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    quicksort_asc( a, 0, N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
5 2 8 2 3 4 1 5 7 -5 -1 -9 2 4 5 7 6 1 4 
-9 -5 -1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 8
```

Comment: You mention a redundant iteration in the OP's code.  My coding indicates that if you change your `if ( l != r )` to instead be `if ( l < r - 1 )` you'll drop from 39 recursions down to 29, for this example, and still get the same answer.  Or have I screwed up somewhere?

Comment: @cdlane It is better to write l + 1 < r.Yes the number of recursions will be less.

Comment: Good answer but the English is almost incomprehensible. What does the paragraph after `lim=l-1` mean (especially "o'k let the indices will have the type int")?

Comment: @S.S.Anne It means that indices should have the type size_t. In this case the expression l - 1 can have a very big value when l is equal to 0 because size_t is unsigned type.